# add groups in js at time of add_item in OpenErp

Tags: javascript, odoo

```
        has_share(function() {
            self.add_items('other', [
                {   label: _t('Share'),
                    callback: self.on_click_share,
                    classname: 'oe_share',
                    groups: 'base.group_no_one' },
                {   label: _t('Embed'),
                    callback: self.on_click_share_link,
                    classname: 'oe_share' },
            ]);
```

i want to add groups: 'base.group_no_one' but it will not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 has_share(function() {
     new session.web.Model('res.users').call('has_group', ['base.group_no_one']).done(function(group_status) {
         if (group_status == true) {
             self.add_items('other', [
                 { label: _t('Share'),
                   callback: self.on_click_share,
                   classname: 'oe_share' },
                 { label: _t('Embed'),
                   callback: self.on_click_share_link,
                   classname: 'oe_share' },
                 ]);
             }
        });
});
```

using this add group at time of add_item.